# nodetool issue in cassandra 3.7

Tags: cassandra

I have cassandra 3.7 installed on centos 7 its running find. when i try to execute nodetool repair or nodetool refresh command it will give me message like

> Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.

I have checked file /etc/default/datastax-agent and below are the details of that

> export JAVA_HOME=/env/config/java/jdk1.8.0_91 
>   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
>   export CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar

Thanks

Comment: It reminds me of a previous similar issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11661
You should check the nodetool script and other scripts it uses. Perhaps, depending your shell and your OS, the control on the version of Java is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Thomas.

Now I am not using Cassandra 3.7 we have switched to 3.0.9 as 3.7 is having many issues as I got this info from Cassandra Slack Channel and 3.0.9 is running well.